# Bash conditional matching and saving the wildcard to a variable

Tags: bash

I want to process the youtube playlist for mpv and I am using a bash script for it.

```
if [[ "$QUTE_URL" == *"$ytstring"*"&index="*"&list="* ]];  then
```

Now I want the Wildcard matched at `&index=` to be echoed / saved to a variable for further processing.

How would I do that?

A sample for $QUTE_URL:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-xLDTN0s_I&index=**3**&list=PLlSUA5AyYAoeDPCjR6weNeiXXJitl4dlc

And I want the 3 in this case, to hand over to youtube-downloader so it knows where to start the playlist. Well maybe I need the list too, the output should look like
mpv -ytdl-raw-options=playlist-start=**3** -ytdl https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=**PL1bauNEiHIgyHtNfI-eIZDUfkNlz_TL2Z**

Comment: What is sample value of `QUTE_URL` and what part you want to save in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match a regular expression:

```
url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-xLDTN0s_I&index=3&list=PLlSUA5AyYAoeDPCjR6weNeiXXJitl4dlc'
if [[ $url =~ \&index=([0-9]*)\& ]]; then
  echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Output:

```
3
```

From `man bash`:

> The element of BASH_REMATCH with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the entire regular expression.  The element of
>          BASH_REMATCH with index n is the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.